# Layering images? Possible z-index use case?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to layer two images in React Native, and I can't find a way to implement it without utilizing z-indexes (which RN doesn't support, correct?).  Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

components/objects can be stacked. try using the following on your stylesheet:

```
    position: absolute,
    top: xxx,
    left: zzz,
```

for the one thats suppose to be top (2nd). you might also want to enclose those images inside a view prior to stacking.

Answer (score 0):

Despite your question around 3 and a half year ago, z-indexes which React-Native supports now.